# Fallback value if column value matches a given value

Tags: sql

I try to fall back to a default value if a specific value occures. Pseudo code would be something like this:

```
IS(GREATEST(
    IFNULL(ist.change_date, ''), 
    IFNULL(a.change_date, ''), 
    IFNULL(co.commented_on, '')
  ), '', NULL) last_updated_tmp
```

It's structured like this

```
IS(EXPRESSION, VALUE_TO_HANDLE, DEFAULT_VALUE)
```

If `EXPRESSION` produces `VALUE_TO_HANDLE` it should return `DEFAULT_VALUE` instead else the result of `EXPRESSION`.

I won't do something like

```
IF(GREATEST(IFNULL(ist.change_date, ''), IFNULL(a.change_date, ''), IFNULL(co.commented_on, '')) = '', NULL, GREATEST(IFNULL(ist.change_date, ''), IFNULL(a.change_date, ''), IFNULL(co.commented_on, '')))
```

Cause that feels dirty.

Comment: I removed my answer due to misunderstanding your question. I know fully understand what you're looking after.

Comment: How about storing your expression in a [temporary variable](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/example-user-variables.html)?

Answer (score 0):

Use [`CASE`](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms181765.aspx)

```
SELECT
    CASE 
        WHEN Expression = Value THEN Default
        ELSE Expression
    END
FROM mytable
```

Comment: I could also use the `IF(EXPRESSION = Default, Default, EXPRESSION)` so it's not what I'm looking for.